# Is it possible to obtain author-year citation style with elsarticle-num?

Tags: citing, natbib, elsarticle

Assume I want to use `elsart-num` by default, but sometimes I want to use author-year citation style to get autho-year citation for some labels. Is it possible to accomplish this?

[image]

My MWE

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2021new,
    title={A new method to fit logistic functions with wind turbines power curves using manufacturer datasheets},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, {Al-Motasem} Ihssan and Alzaareer, Khaled and Harasis, Salman and {Al-Odat}, Zeyad and Obeidat, Mohammad and Mansour, Ayman and Wu, Di and Salem, Qusay},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={16},
    number={2},
    year={2021},
    month={12},
    doi={https://doi.org/10.1049/rpg2.12309}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

[\citeauthor{aldaoudeyeh2021new}, \citeyear{aldaoudeyeh2021new}]

\cite{aldaoudeyeh2021new}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Real quick: Did  you mean to write `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{elsart-num}`?

Comment: @Mico. Yes, I meant `elsarticle-num`

Comment: @Mico. Yes, in `biblatex`, this is very easy, but as for `natbib` with `elsarticle-num`, it is unclear to me how it could be achieved

Comment: To use `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` even though you've loaded `natbib` with the option `numbers`, you need to employ a bibliography style that's capable of producing both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs. `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrvnat` are examples of such bibliography styles. Unfortunately for you, `elsarticle-num` is set to produce numeric-style citation call-outs only. That's why `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` aren't working in the example you showed.

Comment: Ah, I thought this might be the answer even before posting the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Stay tuned: I just figured out a solution. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you (a) load `natbib` with the option `numbers` (which is the default for the `elsarticle` document class) but also (b) employ the `elsarticle-harv` bib style instead of the `elsarticle-num` style. This works because `elsarticle-harv`, unlike `elsarticle-num`, is capable of producing both numeric-style and authoryear-style citation call-outs. Moreover, `elsarticle-num` and `elsarticle-harv` format the bib entries identically.

The only catch is that whereas the `elsarticle-num` bib style does *not* sort the bib entries alphabetically, `elsarticle-harv` does. If the bib entries must be listed in the order in which they are first cited in the document, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `elsarticle-harv.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `elsarticle-harv-nosort.bst`. (Do not edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `elsarticle-harv-nosort.bst` in a text editor. The editor you employ to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Find the two lines that contain just the word `SORT`. (In my copy of the bst file, this word occurs on lines 1486 and 1560.)
- Delete (or comment out) the two `SORT` instructions.
- Save the file `elsarticle-harv-nosort.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you have no idea what the preceding instruction means, you should choose the first option.)
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}` to `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-nosort}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@misc{ m:3001, author = "Mary Miller", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[numbers]{elsarticle} 
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv-nosort}

\begin{document}
\cite{m:3001}, \citeauthor{m:3001}, \citeyear{m:3001}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```